# Pagnation with GET data in the uri - Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

Im trying to paginate results returned by DB. But when I try to get the offset from URI:

`questions/search?content=foobar/4`

`/4` should be the offset but it is assigned to the `$_GET` value.

This is the whole method in the controller:

http://pastebin.com/QFJddMDJ

```
$results = $this->question->search_results_count($content);
$this->load->library('pagination');
$config['total_rows'] = count($results);
$offset = $this->uri->segment(3);
if ($offset == false) $offset = 0;
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pages">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li><a  class="active">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '<li>';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="next">';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['first_link'] = '<<';
$config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['last_link'] = '>>';
$config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['per_page'] = 1;
$config['uri_segment'] = 2;
$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
$config['suffix'] = '?content='.$content;
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'questions/search/';
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

Comment: The query string must be the last thing in your url. Something like /search/4?content=foo works?

Comment: How to seet the base_url in the config?

Comment: Look in your config/config.php file and the entry that says $config['base_url] = xxxxxx;

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I'm sure you know, URIs don't work like that. The query string must be at the end (or before a `#` hash fragment). This query string:

```
questions/search?content=foobar/4
```

Means `$_GET['content'] = 'foobar/4';`

You need to change your pagination URLs to something like this:

```
questions/search/4/?content=foobar
```

The `/` after the 4 there is also optional.

You'll have to remove the query string from your pagination's `$config['base_url']` and instead append it to the links in the view, which sadly involves hacking the pagination class...

Or try this undocumented feature:

```
// After loading the pagination class
$this->pagination->suffix = '{YOUR QUERY STRING}';
```

Or better yet, just add `$config['suffix'] = '{YOUR QUERY STRING}';` to your config before loading the class. This should automatically add the query string to every link's `href`.

Some adjustments to your config area also needed:

```
// Make sure to encode these
// $config['first_link'] = '<<';
$config['first_link'] = '&lt;&lt;';
// $config['last_link'] = '>>';
$config['last_link'] = '&gt;&gt;';

$offset = $this->uri->segment(3);
// Default URI segment is 3, and it's what you use above. Remove this.
// $config['uri_segment'] = 2;

// This should be FALSE (default). Remove it.
// $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;

// This should be FALSE (default) if you're
// using the URI segment as your OFFSET. Remove it.
// $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

// Add your query string
$config['suffix'] = '?content='.$content;
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'questions/search/';
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

Comment: Something like `?content=foobar`. Whatever you want to appear in the href after the page number.

Comment: I made something like this: `$config['suffix'] = '?content='.$content;` But when I create_links() the output is empty string.

Comment: Did you remember to `echo`?... Edit your question and add your full code to your post and I will look at it.

Comment: Done. I pasted in the pastebin.com =)

Comment: I don't see where you're *displaying* the links, there should be a view file where you're using `echo $pagination;`. Does removing the `suffix` part make the links display again? Also you need to remove `page_query_string` in your config. Also make sure to HTML encode those brackets in `$config['first_link'] = '<<';`

Comment: Well I'm displaying in the view. I did this and the result `$data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();     var_dump($data['pagination']);` is "string '' (length=0)"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11041/discussion-between-wesley-murch-and-fakeheal)

Comment: Instead of hacking the `suffix`, you can simply just set `reuse_string_segment` to `TRUE` in the pagination config.