# Codeigniter Pagination - Limit and Limit Offset query strings

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I have config code for Codeigniter's pagination

```
$config['base_url']   = $base_url;
$config['total_rows'] = $total_search_results;
$config['per_page']   = $per_page;
$config['num_links']        = 4;
$config['use_page_numbers'] = FALSE;
$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
$config['query_string_segment'] = 'limit-offset';
```

I have "limit" and "limit-offset" values that are gotten from GET query strings which is where I derive the $per_page value.

However, in the pagination links that are produced, I still want to include the "limit" and "limit-offset" values in a url like

```
www.domain.com/test/?limit=10&limit-offset=20
```

How do we do these using Codeigniter Pagination library?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to @WesleyMurch's answer here at [Pagnation with GET data in the uri - Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504274/pagnation-with-get-data-in-the-uri-codeigniter)

```
// After loading the pagination class
$this->pagination->suffix = '{YOUR QUERY STRING}';
```

Or better yet, just add `$config['suffix'] = '{YOUR QUERY STRING}';` to your config before loading the class.

Answer (score 0):

You must edit your

```
config["base_url"] = www.domain.com/test?limit=xxx;
```

edit

```
config['per_page'] = $this->input->get("limit");
```

This is the complete config :

```
//your base url : www.domain.com/
$config['base_url']   = sprintf("%stest/?limit=%d", $base_url, $this->input->get("limit")); // it will generate : www.domain.com/test?limit=xxx
$config['total_rows'] = $total_search_results;
$config['per_page']   = $this->input->get("limit");
$config['num_links']        = 4;
$config['use_page_numbers'] = FALSE;
$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
$config['query_string_segment'] = 'limit-offset';
```

Then, foreach pagination link will have this format : 
www.domain.com/test/?limit=10&limit-offset=20